# Can not create object of DirectorySearcher class with Visual C++ with project reference of System.DirectoryServices.dll

Tags: visual-c++, soap, timeout, directoryservices, directorysearcher

System.DirectoryServices.dll file has been added successfully to Visual C++ project through References in Solution Explorer.

Microsoft Development Environment 2003 Version 7.1.3088.

Microsoft .Net Framework 1.1 Version 1.1.4322

```
using namespace System::DirectoryServices;//line 1268
void CClassName::MethodName(){
...
    DirectorySearcher* directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher();//line 1701
    directorySearcher->ClientTimeout = 60000;//line 1702
...
}


file.cpp(1701): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'DirectorySearcher'
file.cpp(1701): error C2065: 'directorySearcher' : undeclared identifier
file.cpp(1701): error C2065: 'DirectorySearcher' : undeclared identifier
file.cpp(1702): error C2227: left of '->ClientTimeout' must point to class/struct/union
        type is ''unknown-type''
file.cpp(1268): error C2653: 'System' : is not a class or namespace name
file.cpp(1268): error C2871: 'DirectoryServices' : a namespace with this name does not exist
file.cpp(1702): error C3861: 'directorySearcher': identifier not found, even with argument-dependent lookup
```

By this way I need to set Request Timeout for SOAP WebService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.DirectoryServices` is a .NET wrapper around the C++ [Active Directory Service Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/active-directory-service-interfaces-adsi). If your application is in C++, then just use the C++ libraries.

There's an example of how to search using [`IDirectorySearch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-idirectorysearch) here: [Searching with the IDirectorySearch Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/searching-with-idirectorysearch)